# How to import csv with special character to mysql using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I'm trying to import a csv file with some rows with special character (Á,É etc) and every time the PHP "find" a word with some special character the program just stop importing.
I tryed to use "addslashes" but it didn't work

My code:

```
    $abraArq = fopen($filename,"r");

while(($row = fgetcsv($abraArq,2048,";"))!==FALSE) {
    $sql = "insert into senha (CODIGO_VENDEDOR,NOME_VENDEDOR,STATUS_VENDEDOR,SENHA_URA,DATA_EXPIRACAO) values('$row[0]','".addslashes($row[2])."','$row[3]','$row[7]','$row[8]')";
mysqli_query($conexao,$sql) or die(mysqli_errno($conexao));
}
fclose($abraArq);
```

Comment: Do you have phpMyAdmin ? you could use that to import the file.

Comment: yes..but i'm building a web application to other users import files